# Magento - How to get a customer (user) password

Tags: magento

I make this code in a external php file to get users informations :

```
        $customerCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
        ->addNameToSelect()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
        ->joinAttribute('postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')          
        ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');
```

I want to get also in my request the password of the users.

How can I do that ??

Thanks a lot.

Comment: To clarify... Are you after the password or the MD5 salted password?

Comment: I don't understand well your question Mathew, I want just to get the password and then connect like it is done in this link :http://mysillypointofview.richardferaro.com/2010/03/25/how-to-run-magento-version-1-4-0-1-session-to-external-site/

But not from a formular, I want to let the administrator connect with the user name and pass of a customer, from a page that contains a list of the customers.

Thanks.

Comment: I checked that link, it uses the Magento functions to see if the entered password is the right one. This puts the entered $_POST password through MD5 and sees if the result is the same as the stored one, which is also hashed through MD5. The actual password is not stored on the system at any stage for security reasons, hence you cannot get it back. There is code out there for an admin to log into any account, this may help you if you are writing an admin extension.

Comment: Is there any solution to my problem ? :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your comments, no there is not a solution if you need the cleartext password, and that is a Very Good Thing. If you were able to trivially retrieve a customer's password, that would mean that an attacker would also have this ability.

To prevent that, Magento hashes your password (using MD5 or SHA1, depending on your edition of Magento), and includes a "salt" value to add to the complexity of the password. This is standard cryptographic practice.

The link you posted shows how to let customers use their own passwords to log into multiple sites at once. Aside from the fact that the code on that page isn't terribly good, it won't address your problem.

If you need to log in as a user on the frontend, there are modules to do this or you can write your own. Basically, check to see that you have a valid administrative session with permission to connect to user accounts, and force the login credentials into the session. Keep in mind that this is already problematic from a security standpoint, but it may be necessary for your business.

If you're trying to log into another system you control as your user, you're basically stuck writing the same module on that platform. If you do have/find a platform that lets you retrieve the user's password, stop using it until that flaw is patched. This would be a huge red flag for any system that also deals with sensitive information (e.g. customer info, payment info).

If you have any other questions (or if you provide a little more detail on what you want to accomplish), I'll be happy to help. Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Thanks a lot Joseph, I want exactly to let to the administrator to connect as a customer ; For this purpose, I have found a (french) link that contain some source code to do that from the backend. There is the link : http://benjion.wordpress.com/2011/04/29/magento-se-connecter-en-tant-que-client-depuis-ladmin/ but I don't know how to use it exactly, where shall I paste the code...?? 

I'll be very thankful if you can help with this code.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to execute the code somewhere inside of Magento. I would recommend reading up on how to create a module with a controller and placing the code there. However, if you don't understand what the code does, don't just paste it in somewhere. With a security issue like this, trusting code you found on the internet isn't a great idea.

Comment: any realistic solution to do that ?
I have tried the code alone and in a module but it don't works. :(

Comment: Without knowing more about what you tried, I cannot possibly answer that question. The link you posted has code that seems reasonable (obviously I haven't tried it), but you'll have to dig through it to actually implement it.

Comment: I don't need to show the cleartext password, but need to log as a selected customer, from the backend (and it's possinle only to the administrator). I don't know how to do that exactly, how can I begin... Thanks a lot.

Comment: The link you posted and the responses you got are all ways to do this. You need to become familiar with creating a new module in Magento, and adding a controller action, before you can really approach this. Once you do that, your controller should trigger some code similar to the link you posted. Make sure you are familiar with how Magento's user sessions are initialized. Add ACL configuration to the module to let only allowed administrators control of this function. It's not a trivial change, but there are tutorials for most of the pieces.

Answer (score 2):

You can get customer's hashed password in the following way if you have customer email.

```
$customer_password = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()
->getWebsite()->getId())->loadByEmail($customer_email)->getPasswordHash();
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste the following code in your `connectasAction` in the controller you use and get the correct param:

```
public function connectAsAction() {

if (!Mage::getSingleton('admin/session') ->isAllowed('customer/connectas')) {

echo 'You are not allowed to connect as another user'; return;

}

$customerId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer') ->load($customerId);

if ($customer->getId() != $customerId) { echo 'User not found.'; return; }

$preferedStoreViewId = $customer->getPreferedStoreViewId();

if (!$preferedStoreViewId > 0) {

$customer->getWebsiteId();

$preferedStoreViewId = Mage::app() ->getWebsite($customer->getWebsiteId())

->getDefaultStore() ->getStoreId();

} session_write_close();

//Suppression du cookie 'frontend'

$params = session_get_cookie_params();

setcookie(
           'frontend', 
           '', 
           time() - 42000, 
           $params["path"], 
           $params["domain"], 
           $params["secure"], 
           $params["httponly"] 
         );

//Here we need to write on the session 
//corresponding to the frontend website 

session_regenerate_id(); 
session_name('frontend'); 
session_start(); 

$customer->setPreferedStoreViewId($preferedStoreViewId); 

//We set the customer and its store view 
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore( Mage::getModel('core/store') 
                  ->load($preferedStoreViewId) ); 
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session') 
                      ->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer); 

//We need to write data before continuing 
//in the normal magento process session_write_close();
//Redirect to the front on the specific store view 
$this->_redirectUrl(Mage::app() 
           ->getStore($preferedStoreViewId) 
           ->getBaseUrl()); 
}
```

This is from my blog: http://benjion.wordpress.com/2011/04/29/magento-se-connecter-en-tant-que-client-depuis-ladmin/

Answer (score 0):

You can get customer's hashed password this way (let's say you want a customer depending on email address):

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer_api');
    $data = $customer->items(array('email' => customeremail));return $data['password'];
```